# Error C# Dynamics CRM: The authentication endpoint Username was not found on the configured Secure Token Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dynamics-crm, federation

We're facing an error while trying to deploy a WCF webservice in a server. While connecting to Dynamics (CRM on premise) we get this error: The authentication endpoint Username was not found on the configured Secure Token Service

If we test it locally, it's working but if the deploy the webservice in the server, this is the code which performs the login:

```
 Uri serviceUri = new Uri(OrgServiceUri);
                proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceUri, null, authCredentials, null);
                proxy.EnableProxyTypes();
                _service = (IOrganizationService)proxy;
                Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)_service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;
                if (userid != Guid.Empty)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(userid);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
```

Any guess?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found it was an issue with ADFS service per-se, networking related, since it wasnt able to connect SSO site. After fixing that, it started to work as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the user you have set up as the service account has Read/Write access to CRM and has a security role assigned that enables it to log into CRM remotely.

Next, make sure the Username endpoint is configured in the ADFS deployment that this CRM org is using:

Log onto the ADFS server and open the ADFS management console. Go to ADFS > Service > Endpoints
You’ll see a list of endpoint URLs here. Find the one for /adfs/services/trust/13/username of type WS-Trust 1.3
Make sure that this endpoint has “Yes” set for both the Enabled and Proxy Enabled settings.
If you have to make a change to this endpoint, after making the change re-start the ADFS server and the CRM server, then try to register again.

Lastly, if the above looks okay, it could be a resolution or routing issue blocking the connection. Make sure that there are external DNS entries for the path to your ADFS server. Also, make sure that your firewall permits external access to the ADFS server. If you are able to, try to use a computer that is outside of your domain to navigate directly to the ADFS server to test its accessibility.

This is a problem with the same error as you, and it has been resolved, you can refer to:  [The authentication endpoint Username was not found on the configured Secure Token Service](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/223369/the-authentication-endpoint-username-was-not-found-on-the-configured-secure-token-service)

Comment: Finally we found it was an issue with ADFS service per-se, networking related, since it wasnt able to connect SSO site. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ADFS **on-prem**, the **ADFS windows service** might be stopped (Because of a power failure / unexpected server restart).

You just need to **start** it.